# Facebook Comment Plugin Synced with Page?

Tags: facebook, api, plugins, comments

I'm using the Facebook Comment plugin for comments on my site. I was hoping that comments made to links shared on my Facebook Page would also show up on my website.

For example, if I share a link to a blog post on my Facebook Page, and someone comments directly to that shared link, that comment does not also appear on the website.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to sync these two?

Answer (score 0):

I think comments are self-contained. You could maybe use the API to build something that shares comments on your page with comments on your blog.